# How to reorder a quadword vector data using Neon Intrinsics?

Tags: arm, neon

The question is related to ARM NEON intrinsics.
Iam using ARM neon intrinsics for FIR implementation.
I want to reorder a quadword vector data.
For example,
There are four 32 bit elements in a Neon register - say, Q0 - which is of size 128 bit.

A3 A2 A1 A0

I want to reorder Q0 as A0 A1 A2 A3.

Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Reading http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html together with the ARM infocenter, I think the following would do what you ask:

```
    uint32x2_t dvec_h = vget_high_u32(qvec);
    uint32x2_t dvec_l = vget_low_u32(qvec);

    dvec_h = vrev64_u32(dvec_h);
    dvec_l = vrev64_u32(dvec_l);

    qvec = vcombine_u32(dvec_h, dvec_l);
```

In assembly, this could be written simply as:

```
    VSWP      d0, d1
    VREV64.32 q0, q0
```

Comment: Might a `vrev64q_u32` do it in one step?  Also, `vzip_u32` might make things a little more compact. Something like `vzip_u32(vget_high_u32(x), vget_low_u32(x))` might also work. Also see [Coding for NEON - Part 5: Rearranging Vectors](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/coding-for-neon---part-5-rearranging-vectors).

Comment: @jww: no idea :) Haven't done NEON in years, and don't know if that was available at the time. Suggest you post your own answer.